# How to set Cache-Control for static content in war file

Tags: java, jax-rs, http-caching

When I deploy a Java web application as a war file and have some static resources (html, js, css) packaged up in my war file, how do I control the `Cache-Control` headers that the application server should use when serving those files?  I'm happy for it to be a blanket thing (all static content from war file is given the same cache policy).

I'm using Tomcat (from AWS Elastic Beanstalk) and finding no `Cache-Control` header is set by default.

Comment: What toolkit are you using? Spring 4.1 makes this a one-liner; other technologies will have different requirements.

Comment: It's a pretty simple JAX-RS web application.  Not using Spring.